# Laravel change connection in Validator not working

Tags: php, database, validation, laravel

I have a System, built with Laravel that is connected in two databases, one with mysql and other is mssql. My default connection is mysql:

```
'default' => 'mysql',
```

and

```
'mysql' => [
        'driver'    => 'mysql',
        'host'      => 'localhost',
        'database'  => 'qdf_api',
        'username'  => 'root',
        'password'  => '',
        'charset'   => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix'    => '',
        'strict'    => false,
    ],

'sqlsrv' => [
        'driver'   => 'sqlsrv',
        'host'     => '192.168.3.248,51433',
        'database' => 'sample_test',
        'username' => 'joene',
        'password' => 'password',
        'charset'  => 'utf8',
        'prefix'   => '',
    ],
```

Then my controller:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    Validator::extend('unique_multiple', function ($attribute, $value, $parameters)
    {
        // Get table name from first parameter
        $table = array_shift($parameters);

        // Build the query
        $query = DB::table($table);

        // Add the field conditions
        foreach ($parameters as $i => $field)
            $query->where($field, $value[$i]);

        // Validation result will be false if any rows match the combination
        return ($query->count() == 0);
    });


    $file = Input::file('file');
    $count = 0;

    Excel::load($file, function($reader) use ($count) {

        $results = $reader->get()->toArray();
        // Set connection to sqlsrv
        $verifier = App::make('validation.presence');
        $verifier->setConnection('sqlsrv');

        foreach ($results as $key => $value) {

            $validator = Validator::make(
                // Validator data goes here
                array(
                    'unique_fields' => array($value['telephone'], $value['columnheadername'])
                ),
                // Validator rules go here
                array(
                    'unique_fields' => 'unique_multiple:Deliveries,Telephone,ColumnHeaderName',
                    'file' => 'required'
                )
            );

            $validator->setPresenceVerifier($verifier);


            if ($validator->fails()) 
            {
                return Redirect::to('delivery/create')->withErrors($validator);
            }
            else
            {
                $deliveries = new Delivery();
                $deliveries->Title                  = $value['title'];
                $deliveries->Firstname              = $value['firstname'];
                $deliveries->Surname                = $value['surname'];
                $deliveries->Address1               = $value['address1'];
                $deliveries->Address2               = $value['address2'];
                $deliveries->Address3               = $value['address3'];
                $deliveries->Address4               = $value['address4'];
                $deliveries->Town                   = $value['town'];
                $deliveries->County                 = $value['county'];
                $deliveries->Postcode               = $value['postcode'];
                $deliveries->Telephone              = $value['telephone'];
                $deliveries->Email                  = $value['email'];
                $deliveries->AgeBracket             = $value['agebracket'];
                $deliveries->Gender                 = $value['gender'];
                $deliveries->Filename               = $value['filename'];
                $deliveries->CalledDate             = $value['calleddate'];
                $deliveries->ColumnHeaderName       = $value['columnheadername'];
                $deliveries->Answer1                = $value['answer1'];
                $deliveries->Answer2                = $value['answer2'];
                $deliveries->Answer3                = $value['answer3'];
                $deliveries->Answer4                = $value['answer4'];
                $deliveries->Answer5                = $value['answer5'];
                $deliveries->HomeOwner              = $value['residentialstatus'];
                $deliveries->MaritalStatus          = $value['maritalstatus'];
                $deliveries->WorkStatus             = $value['incomebracket'];
                if($deliveries->save()){$count++;}
            }
        }

        Session::flash('alert-success', 'Data Uploaded Successfully! '.$count.' leads uploaded');
    }); 

        return Redirect::to('delivery/create');   
}
```

You can see the line:

```
$verifier = App::make('validation.presence');
$verifier->setConnection('sqlsrv');
```

And still got this error:

```
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'qdf_api.deliveries' doesn't exist (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `Deliveries` where `Telephone` = 01482828164 and `ColumnHeaderName` = EDF_3320)
```

The deliveries table is on my `sample_test` database which is in `sqlsrv` connection. That's why I am switching to the `sqlsrv` connection but seems not working?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have same database name for both connection, and you might have added **qdf_api** database name in your .env file. Because of that you're getting error.

Comment: Hi. My env has no qdf_api. And yes I have two databases I am connecting at. I am trying to direct the validation in a specific database connection which for now doesn't work.

Comment: In your .env file, what is set in front of `DATABASE` key

Comment: DB_HOST=localhost
DB_DATABASE=hrs
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=

Comment: It's HRS so that should not be a problem cause I don't see any errors related to hrs? Plus I already remove the env in the database.php

Comment: @jackhammer013 I've updated my answer, see if this helps.

Comment: DB::connection('sqlsrv')->select(...); is used for querying databases. My problem is regarding validation so I won't be able to use it. My .env now is now empty. My main connection resides in database.php which I included in my post.

Comment: @jackhammer013 I'm not sure where it is failing, coz you're doing it all correct.